# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'WScript' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, skype

WScript.ConnectObject(oSkype, "Skype_");

when connect event to skype than below error come in above syntax
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'WScript' is undefined

Comment: You're going to have to add more detail than that. Where are you running the script (web/file/etc)? what language are you using (jscript/vbscript/etc)? what is oSkype?

Answer (score 2):

The WScript.Object is provided by the w/cscript.exe script host. If you execute JScript in other contexts (browser, server, ... ), you'll have to try the language's function (GetObject, CreateObject, new ActiveXObject) or the equivalent function of that host.